# Does it make any sense to ask for mutual inductance between a wire and a coil?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

I have been asked to work out the mutual inductance coefficient between a circular spire of $N=1$ turns and radius $R$ and an infinite wire contained in the plane in which the spire lies. This, however, makes no sense to me. I can't see the spire inducting anything on the wire, so what sense does it make to ask about the mutual inductance coefficient?

Comment: I am not sure what a "spire" is in the context of your question but I think you are asked to calculate this contour integral https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance#Mutual_inductance_of_two_wire_loops . Whatever "spire" may mean your question implies a known plane closed curve and a straight line, so the two will not be always perpendicular to each other and thus the mutual inductance will likely be not zero. The contour for the straight line is as described by @Vincent_Fratelli, a semi-circle closing a finite segment of the line with its radius increasing to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider that the infinite wire closes to infinity, staying in the same plane. So you just have to compute the flux of the field of the wire across the circular spire.

The other computation (flux of the flied of the spire across the wire) would be more tricky !

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I can't see what you mean by "closes to infinity". The thing I can't figure out is how can there be any flux across the wire

Comment: If you close the wire at infinity while remaining in the plane of the spire, it delimits a flat surface that leans on the closed contour. There is a flux of the field of the spire through this flat surface.

Comment: And is that rigorous? I mean, why can we "close the wire at infinity" in that way you mention? Aren't we simply dealing with an infinite length wire? Why should we regard it as closed at infinity? What is the intuition behind that?

Comment: An infinite wire do not exist. We simply want to say that in the region that interests us the field is the same as if the wire were infinite. To calculate the flux of the field of the wire through the turn, it is easy to understand. For the reciprocal, we know that the coefficients of inductance are equal even if it is not intuitive. Do not forget that the flux is a tool. It is the circulation of the non-conservative electric field generated by the coil that interests us. And one can understand that the contribution to this circulation of the distant parts of the circuit is not important.